# How to call external typescript class that is not part of the solution from Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, crm

I am developing a CRM solution using Angular, where end users can design their own forms using drag and drop. Now they should be able to write their own custom logic in a typescript class for a particular form.
This class will have few methods(that will be know to us like onSave, onInitialize). And these methods can be called when that particular form loads.

Is there any way to call that external typescript class (that is not part of our angular solution) at runtime? I guess, i need to transpile it to Javascript first and then somehow attach it to the Angular app at runtime, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Confused why you can't just write a class and import it? Also all of your code is transpiled to JS upfront otherwise it couldn't run in the browser, there's no "when" involved there. Unless Angular does strange things.

Comment: Thanks, the class is created by end user, it's not part of our solution. How to import it at runtime?

Comment: You'll have to compile it to JS, store it somewhere (s3 bucket, etc) and then load it dynamically at run time. Not sure you can do that though.

Comment: Okaay.. Thanks for the help :)